# Cannot access 'kotlin.collections.Collection' which is a supertype of 'org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler'

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

[image]

I got the above error after i add `` Plugins{ `kotlin`} `` to my build.gradle.kts file.

I have Google this problem and rebuild after delete all .gradle、.idea dir, but this problem still occurs. Additionally, i tried invalidate caches, but not work.

Any ideas for this problem?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Adding kotlin to your project?

Comment: For me it happened when updating Gradle, Kotlin and Android Studio. Any luck ?

Answer (score 19):

You can try to delete Cache folder of Android Studio manually `~/Library/Caches/Google/AndroidStudio4.2`

I had the same problem when upgrading Android Studio 4.2, Kotlin 1.5, and Gradle 7.0. This solution fixed my problem

Comment: Do you know the path for Windows ? I've tried `gradlew cleanBuildCache` with no luck so far

Comment: I'm not familiar with Windows, but I think you can try `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\AndroidStudio4.2`

Comment: My machine OS is `Debian 10 Buster` and path for this dir is: `~/.cache/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3/`

Comment: This did help, much appreciated!

Comment: So "Invalidate caches & restart" in AS which didn't help me actually doesn't delete all caches? OMG.

Comment: This solution worked for me as well. Be sure to delete the `caches` folder (`~/.cache/Google/AndroidStudioX`), not the regular data folder (`~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudioX`)